# Liferay create a custom PanelCategory for multiple portlet

Tags: eclipse, liferay, liferay-7

I use Liferay 7.2 and Liferay IDE (eclipse). I created two separate Liferay admin portlet to creating a view for the database entries. I added in the first portlet "Teachers" a new panel called school with this generated code in application.list Package.

here is the code of - PanelApp.java

```
    @Component(
    immediate = true,
    property = {
        "panel.app.order:Integer=300",
        "panel.category.key=" + TeachersPanelCategoryKeys.CONTROL_PANEL_CATEGORY
    },
    service = PanelApp.class
)
public class TeachersPanelApp extends BasePanelApp {

    @Override
    public String getPortletId() {
        return TeachersPortletKeys.TEACHERS;
    }

    @Override
    @Reference(
        target = "(javax.portlet.name=" + TeachersPortletKeys.TEACHERS+ ")",
        unbind = "-"
    )
    public void setPortlet(Portlet portlet) {
        super.setPortlet(portlet);
    }

}
```

.

```
   public class TeachersPanelCategoryKeys {
    
        public static final String CONTROL_PANEL_CATEGORY = "Teachers";
    
    }
```

And here is the code of - PanelCategory.java

```java
@Component(
immediate = true,
property = {
    "panel.category.key=" + PanelCategoryKeys.SITE_ADMINISTRATION,
    "panel.category.order:Integer=300"
},
service = PanelCategory.class)

public class TeachersPanelCategory extends BasePanelCategory {

@Override
public String getKey() {
    return TeachersPanelCategoryKeys.CONTROL_PANEL_CATEGORY;
}

@Override
public String getLabel(Locale locale) {
    return LanguageUtil.get(locale, "School");
}}
```

And here is the code of portlet.java

```
    @Component(
        immediate = true,
        property = {
            "com.liferay.portlet.add-default-resource=true",
            "com.liferay.portlet.display-category=category.hidden",
            "com.liferay.portlet.header-portlet-css=/css/main.css",
            "com.liferay.portlet.layout-cacheable=true",
            "com.liferay.portlet.private-request-attributes=false",
            "com.liferay.portlet.private-session-attributes=false",
            "com.liferay.portlet.render-weight=50",
            "com.liferay.portlet.use-default-template=true",
            "javax.portlet.display-name=Teachers",
            "javax.portlet.expiration-cache=0",
            "javax.portlet.init-param.template-path=/",
            "javax.portlet.init-param.view-template=/view.jsp",
            "javax.portlet.name=" + TeachersPortletKeys.TEACHERS,
            "javax.portlet.resource-bundle=content.Language",
            "javax.portlet.security-role-ref=power-user,user",
    
        },
        service = Portlet.class
    )
    public class TeachersPortlet extends MVCPortlet {
 // some code to get entries from db
        
        
        @Override
        public void doView(final RenderRequest renderRequest, final RenderResponse renderResponse)
                throws IOException, PortletException {
    
// some code
```

Now I want to add the second created portlet "Students" under the same Panel "School". I created it in the same way as "Teachers" but now I have two school panel. As it is shown in the image below.

[image: Example panel]

I just want to display one panel category called school that contain both Teachers and Students in the list.

I do not know how I can think to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're implementing a `TeachersPanelCategory`, I'm assuming you're also implementing a `StudentsPanelCategory`. From a naming perspective, I'd have expected a SchoolPanelCategory.

I'm currently at a loss of how the ControlPanel portlets actually declare their associated panel, but that place would be where you pick the common "school" panel and use the same spelling for both.

In other words: If you deploy two panels with the same name, I'd expect exactly what you document here. Make sure you're only deploying one of them

Edit: I'd like to know what `TeachersPanelCategoryKeys.CONTROL_PANEL_CATEGORY` is defined as, and the corresponding (assumed, not shown) `StudentsPanelCategoryKeys.CONTROL_PANEL_CATEGORY`. Both categories have the same label, but if they have different keys, they'll be different. I'm not sure what happens when you deploy two components with the same key: You should deploy only one.

Edit2: I've missed the code before: You're producing the key to your first category as "Teachers", and the label as "School". I'm assuming that the key for your other category is "Students". Liferay organizes the categories by key - and if the keys are different, then you'll end up with two different categories. Make their key more similar to their name (e.g. create a single `SchoolCategory` and associate your portlets/panelApps with that:

```
@Component(
immediate = true,
property = {
    "panel.category.key=" + PanelCategoryKeys.SITE_ADMINISTRATION,
    "panel.category.order:Integer=300"
},
service = PanelCategory.class)

public class SchoolPanelCategory extends BasePanelCategory {

  @Override
  public String getKey() {
    return "school"; // this is the category that you want to associate with
  }

  @Override
  public String getLabel(Locale locale) {
    return LanguageUtil.get(locale, "School");
  }
}
```

and

```
@Component(
  immediate = true,
  property = {
    "panel.app.order:Integer=300",
    "panel.category.key=school" // referencing the category created above
      // (use the same for your StudentsPanelApp)
    },
    service = PanelApp.class
)
public class TeachersPanelApp extends BasePanelApp {

  @Override
  public String getPortletId() {
    return TeachersPortletKeys.TEACHERS;
  }

  @Override
  @Reference(
    target = "(javax.portlet.name=" + TeachersPortletKeys.TEACHERS+ ")",
    unbind = "-"
  )
  public void setPortlet(Portlet portlet) {
    super.setPortlet(portlet);
  }
}
```

(See the one-line comments within the code for the critical lines. Replace with proper constants if you like)

Comment: thanks for your answer.
It is right what you expected as I developed both in the same way. The question here is if I only deployed one and created a School Panel school with Teachers portlet inside it , how can I include students Portlet inside it as well.
If you can give me a detailed answer as much as possible then I would be thankful because I am still new to using Liferay.

Comment: Can you show some [mcve] code of your Portlet and PanelApp? (add them to your question please) No implementation necessary, just the `@Component` with their class declarations

Comment: I did. I have added the Teachers code parts

Comment: Do you have any idea ?

Comment: after a good night's sleep: Yes, see the edit

Comment: It was a great detailed answer. Thank you